# How to use temporary files in AWS - moving from BytesIO

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, pdf-generation

I have a Django app hosted on Heroku, with the static files in an AWS bucket. On my localhost I had been using xhtml2pdf to render some pdfs. I have been using the code below. Does  anyone know how I could achieve something similar with AWS bucket (possibly using Boto3)?

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template=get_template(template_src)
    html=template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()

    
    pdf=pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

Comment: So `template_src` would be s3 file?